# Visual force Page in salesforce

Tags: visualforce, workflow

I have created the visual force page template in the Email Alert in workflow rule

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="SOA - User {!$User.Username}  does not have JDE Alias assigned !!!" recipientType="user"  relatedToType="Order_Configuration__c" >
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <html>
        <body>
        <center>


              Click on below link to go to this user setup:
              <link to user>----how to write code for linking the usersetup page of salesforce</br></p>
             </center>
             </body>

            </html>
            </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
          </messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Visual force page template should go  to the email,I want

**link to user - what i have to write code for if i click this link it will link to user setup page of Salesforce ,Please anayone guide me for the Answer**

Comment: WORKFLOW RULE STATES THAT when order object contains Jde user alias field if this field is empty,when creating the new order, the mail will sent, i want that the user who creates the order instance

Comment: I have tried like this  Click on below link to go to this user setup:
              "{!$order.Order_Owner__c}.{system.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL()}/{!$user.id}"