# Customization and Apex class

Tags: visualforce, customization

I have created the new order record in salesforce,for Particular Record, owner field is updated with the username who created the order record

I want to take the instance of salesforce organization with the help of Owner name

for example owner of the record is somename

i  want to take the current instance of the somename https://getinstance.salesforce.com with the help of ownername

**How?
Please anyone Guide me for the Answer**

**I have tried Like this:
{!$orderOwner.getinstancename()}/{!$userid}
but it is not working Guide Me the answer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query your current Salesforce.com instance from Apex code:

```
String instance = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();
system.debug(instance);
```

[image]

This will give you complete host name, you will need to break it using any string method to get the exact instance name.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="myController"  >
  <apex:form id="form1">
      <br />
      <apex:outputText id="urlString" value="{!url}"></apex:outputText>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class myController {
    public string url{
        get {
            if (this.url == null)
                this.url = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();
            return this.url; }
        set;
        }

}
```

Comment: i want with the help of owner name of the particular record to get the instance @mahmood

Comment: Instance will remain the same in the org, regardless of the owner of any record whatsoever. May be, it will be clearer for us and be able to help you better if you share your requirements in detail here.

Comment: i want to access in the visualforce page code How?http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145988/visual-force-page-in-salesforce @mahmood

Comment: can you guide me for that @Mahmood

Comment: Do you have controller in you VF page? if yes, create a property and set it with the instance name you are looking for, then 'get' that property in your VF page.

Comment: can you share some controller code for my purpose@Mahmood

Comment: Check the updated reply. I have tested the VF page and url is appearing fine. Plz check at your end.

Comment: I want after controller, I want Visualforce component ,i want to use the value in visual force page template for email alert in salesforce

Comment: please provide the visual force component code for the same scenario

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146014/apex-class-and-visual-force @Mahmood please answer me here