# Getting the salesforce URL server instance from Visualforce Email template?

Tags: visualforce, workflow, visualforce-component

I have the Apex class code:

```
public class myController {
    public string url{
        get {
            if (this.url == null)
                this.url = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();
            return this.url; }
        set;
        }

}
```

I have Visualforcetemplate code for email alert in workflow rule:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate  recipientType="user"  relatedToType="order">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <html>
        <body>
        <center>
            <p><br>

              Click on below link to go to this user setup:
              "**I want to use the instance here**/{!$User.Id}"
              </br></p>
             </center>
             </body>

            </html>
            </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
          </messaging:emailTemplate>
```

**How to write the visualforce component code for accessing the instance there?**in Visualforce page template in email alert in salesforce

**Please anyone guide me for the Answer**

I have tried :

```
<apex:component controller="myController" access="global">
<apex:value="{!myController}" var="s">
<!s.uri>
</apex:value>
</apex:component>
```

**The above one is correct?**

Comment: You want the URL to be shown on the VF page component? What is the use of email template and VF page?

Comment: No I am writing the Workflow rule, if the condition statisfied then the email should sent to the particular user with the help of email alert to carry the instance also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it is not possible, you can upvote the idea [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000b3PjAAI). There is workaround, which I haven't tested myself,

1. You can hard-code the org url and put it your email template
2. You can create a custom label, and put the url in there, then call that custom label from within your email template (just to be controllable and less static than option 1)

**Custom Label**
[image]

Then in your template use this merge field `{!$Label.URL}/{! $User.Id}` which results in the following:

> https://[instancename].salesforce.com/[userid]

**EDIT**
Another solution that is possible, it to use visualfore email templates and use vf component to have the url dynamically and call that component in vf email template. Example given below:

**VF Component**

```
<apex:component controller="myController" access="global">
  <p />
  <apex:outputLink id="urlString" value="{!url}/{!$User.Id}" >{!url}/{!$User.Id}</apex:outputLink>
</apex:component>
```

Name it "URL". You already have the controller.

Then use the above vf component in your email template , something like

```
<messaging:emailTemplate  recipientType="user"  relatedToType="order">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
   <html>
      <body>
         <center>
            <p>
               <br>
               Click on below link to go to this user setup:
               <c:URL/>/{!$User.Id}"
               </br>
            </p>
         </center>
      </body>
   </html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
```

If you get into trouble or stuck, check this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_with_apex.htm) out as well, as I haven't tested the above code myself.

Comment: how to place the value there in custom label,I have to get through the apex class then the value should be placed in custom label,Is it possible

Comment: can you guide me for Visualforce component code for place the value there?@Mahmood,if we create using Custom label,if another user creates the record for them different url will be there for this reason i want visualforce component code

Comment: please Dont Mistaken me @Mahmood

Comment: guide me for the Custom component code @Mahmood

Comment: In output Link is not Displaying , only text is displaying @Mahmood can you change the code in output link is dispalying

Comment: Everything is correct ,but link is not displaying @Mahmood

Comment: what is it showing?

Comment: it is displaying like text value,it is not showing as link

Comment: simply put it inside, <a href=" [component]/[userid]" />

Comment: Now in output nothing is showing @Mahmood

Comment: where i have to put <a href> in vsualforce component

Comment: href doesn't seem to work. Can you try this 
`<apex:outputLink value="<c:url>/{! $User.Id}" ><c:url>/{! $User.Id}</apex:outputLink>`

Comment: it is also displaying like text only

Comment: what we are made mistake why it is displaying like text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47464/discussion-between-mahmood-and-user36188).

Comment: Can you join in discussion chat @Mahmood

Comment: I have a query @Mahmood can you please answer for this question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147651/how-to-get-the-username-of-salesforce-user-and-count-using-visual-force-page/147656#147656

Comment: Lets have a discussion here
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47464/discussion-between-mahmood-and-user36188

Comment: I have a doubt regarding the same question @Mahmood if you are free can we join in disussion chat

Comment: sure. join the same room.