# How to get the username of salesforce user and count using Visual Force Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created the Visualforce Page,I am giving the page access to all users such as System administrator user and internal users,I have created two new custom fields in account object such as Last Viewed user and count of the particular user

If sys administartor user view the page then the account object of the record,last Viewed user as sys administrator name and count will be 1,now another internal user viewing the page then last viewed user as internaluser name and now also count will be 1, because that particular user viewing the page now only,so his count will be 1

**How to take the count Value for particular user and user name and how to store the value in Record of Account Object,Please Anyone Guide me for the Answer** using Visual force and apex class

I have Tried:

Apex class:

```
public class DisplayPage {   
   public Decimal ViewCount {get; set;}


    public DisplayPage(ApexPages.StandardController Controller) {
        this.ViewCount = 0;
        TotalRecordUpdate();  
    }

    public void TotalRecordUpdate(){
        Id profileId = UserInfo.getProfileId();
        List<Page_View__c> pageViews = [SELECT Id, Count__c,AddsName_c__c FROM Page_View__c WHERE  AddsName_c__c = :profileId ];
       // system.debug(AddsName_c__c);
        system.debug(pageViews);
        system.debug(profileId);


        if(pageViews.size() == 0){
           Page_View__c pageView = new Page_View__c(Count__c = 1, AddsName_c__c = profileId);
           system.debug(pageView);
           this.ViewCount = 1;
        }else{
           pageViews[0].Count__c += 1;
           this.ViewCount = pageViews[0].Count__c;
           update pageViews[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Force Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="Displaypage" action="{!updateCount}">
<apex:form >
<apex:actionFunction name="updateCount" action="{!updateCount}" reRender="" />

<script>
    addEventListener("load", updateCount, false);
</script>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

But it is Not working?
Please anyone Share the Logic and Answer

Comment: you can create separate object with all the accountId, user name, number of hits etc. attributes and store those values

Comment: Can you tell us more about what are you trying to achieve ... if you are thinking about locking the record based on number of users accessing the record, there are few issues with this way called pessimistic record locking

Comment: @AmrIbrahim If the user view the  the visualforce page ,his user name should be stored in the account  old record of salesforce in the Custom field called Last Viewed user and how many times that particular user view the page should be stored in count field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

First of all, I don't think you need to use "Account" object or any other standard object for this requirement. You should go for the custom object, which in your case is, "Page_Views__c". And it should have at least these two fields:

1. LastViewedBy (lookup to User)
2. Count (Numeric, displaying the number of times this user has visited this page)

**Logic**

When a user is navigating to this VF page, you should check two things:

1. If user record is not present in the pageview object, then `INSERT` record with user-lookup and count (1).
2. If user record is present, then `UPDATE` with Count = +1

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Page_Views__c" action="{!TotalRecordUpdate}" extensions="Displaypage" >
   <apex:form id="PageCount">
      <apex:actionFunction name="updateCount" action="{!updateCount}" reRender="PageCount" />
      Current user: {! $User.UserName } <br/>
      Page Count: {!ViewCount}
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class DisplayPage {   
   public Decimal ViewCount {get; set;}

    public DisplayPage(ApexPages.StandardController Controller) {
        this.ViewCount = 0;
        //TotalRecordUpdate();  // no need to call dml or dml function in constructor
    }

    public void TotalRecordUpdate(){
        Id userid = UserInfo.getUserId();
        List<Page_View__c> pageViews = [SELECT Last_Viewed_By__c, Page_view_count__c FROM Page_View__c WHERE  Last_Viewed_By__c = : userid ];
   // system.debug(AddsName_c__c);
   if (pageViews.size() > 0 ){
       // record present, use Update
       ViewCount = pageViews[0].Page_view_Count__c +1;
       pageViews[0].Page_view_count__c = ViewCount;
       Update pageViews[0];
   }
        else{
            // record not present, Insert
            Page_View__c pv = new Page_View__c();
            pv.LastViewedBy = userid;
            ViewCount = 1;
            pv.Count__c = ViewCount;

            Insert pv;
            ViewCount = 1;
        }

    }
}
```

P.S. I have not tested the code above, just on-the-fly, so test it please.

Comment: ok i will test it and i will tell what is my problem

Comment: while clicking the preview in the Visual force page it is Showing like that DML currently not allowed

An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

Comment: I updated the code and it should not display the error that you were having. But I have tested the code myself and @LanceShi was right. It is giving error "DML currently not allowed". I shall look into his suggestion and see any other workaround. In the meantime, you too, check for other solutions.

Comment: ok Mahmood Meanwhile i will check for alternate Solution let me know if you find any alternate answer,Thank you for spending time with me

Comment: can you tell the Reason why this error is Happening @Mahmood

Comment: Calling DML in vf page controller constructor creates a huge security concern, that's why it is not allowed. Review [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28833/why-is-dml-not-allowed-in-constructor) thread.

Comment: I have updated the code, and used "Action" attribute on the apex page level to call the method and removed the method call from constructor. It is working and I have tested it but it might not be the best practice. I haven't worked on JS remoting but will explore it. I suggest you do the same.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really think you can do a DML in your page action or controller's constructor. Nor should you do it. Alternatively, you can make a Javascript remoting call to your controller's static method. And do the DML in your static method. Hope this make sense.

Comment: I am not getting your point ,how to store the count Value for every user, for eg: system admin user count will be 3,,sys admin user view the page three times only and internal user count will be 2, can you please share the code for my criteria @Lanceshi

Comment: Here actually mentioned as pageView object instead of account Object

Comment: guide me the code of apex class and Visual force page

Comment: please provide me the code @Lanceshi,I have tried from my side so many logics I am not able to store the count field value for seperate user ,Guide me for the Answer

Comment: why we have to use Remote action in apex class? what is the use? @Lance shi