# How to give Permission to create sandbox?

Tags: apex, sandbox

I have one full copy sandbox and I would like to create one more sandbox to backup. I'm not able to find Sandbox in Setup--Data management. I am a system admin user. What permission i need to create Sandbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should login to Production environment to create sandbox and should have `Manage Sandbox` permission at your profile level.

Comment: can you please answer for this question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147651/how-to-get-the-username-of-salesforce-user-and-count-using-visual-force-page/147656#147656 @Santanu Boral