# Execution of Visual Force page using Apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce

I Have a Apex class:

```
global with sharing class AccountRemoter {



    public String accountName { get; set; }

    public static Account account { get; set; }

    public AccountRemoter() { } // empty constructor



    @RemoteAction

    global static list<Account> getAccount(String accountName) {

        list<account> account1 = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Type, NumberOfEmployees

                   FROM Account WHERE Name = :accountName];

        return account1;

    }

}
```

Visual Force Page:

```
<apex:page controller="AccountRemoter">

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function getRemoteAccount() {

        var accountName = document.getElementById('acctSearch').value;



        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(

            '{!$RemoteAction.AccountRemoter.getAccount}',

            accountName,

            function(result, event){

                if (event.status) {

                    // Get DOM IDs for HTML and Visualforce elements like this

                    document.getElementById('remoteAcctId').innerHTML = result.Id

                    document.getElementById(

                        "{!$Component.block.blockSection.secondItem.acctNumEmployees}"

                        ).innerHTML = result.NumberOfEmployees;

                } else if (event.type === 'exception') {

                    document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML =

                        event.message + "<br/>\n<pre>" + event.where + "</pre>";

                } else {

                    document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = event.message;

                }

            },

            {escape: true}

        );
    }

    </script>



    <input id="acctSearch" type="text"/>

    <button onclick="getRemoteAccount()">Get Account</button>

    <div id="responseErrors"></div>



    <apex:pageBlock id="block">

        <apex:pageBlockSection id="blockSection" columns="2">

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="firstItem">

                <span id="remoteAcctId"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="secondItem">

                <apex:outputText id="acctNumEmployees"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Output for the Above Code:

[image]

**But the output is Showing is undefined and undefined?when entering the account in the search account textbox? why? I want perfect output and why we have to use @Remote action annotation in the Apex class? what is the use?Please anyone guide me for the Answer**

Comment: if anybody knows please answer for this Question also   http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147651/how-to-get-the-username-of-salesforce-user-and-count-using-visual-force-page for the this question only I am struggling to read Remote Action Annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Apex code return a list of Account objects not a single Account object so you need to handle the `result` value accordingly:

```
if (event.status) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        var account = result[i];
        var id = account.Id;
        var n = result.NumberOfEmployees;
        // You will need to create e.g. a table here
        console.log('id=' + id + ' n=' + n);
    }
}
```

You get `undefined` when you try to access a field of a JavaScript object that does not exist.

Note that the debug tools in browser's are excellent and a small investment in time learning about them will quickly pay back.

Have you considered not using JavaScript here? You can write a Visualforce page that has no JavaScript that does the same thing with much less code.

Comment: can you suggest the answer for this question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147651/how-to-get-the-username-of-salesforce-user-and-count-using-visual-force-page @Keithc